# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Not found cos://mybucket.myservicename/checkpoint/offsets

Tags: scala, spark-structured-streaming, analytics-engine, stocator

I'm trying to use Spark Structured Streaming 2.3 to read data from Kafka (IBM Message Hub) and save it into IBM Cloud Object Storage on a 1.1 IBM Analytics Engine Cluster.

After creating the cluster, ssh into it:

```sh
$ ssh clsadmin@myclusterid.bi.services.eu-gb.bluemix.net
```

Create a `jaas.conf` file required for spark to talk to Message Hub:

```sh
$ cat << EOF > jaas.conf
KafkaClient {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    serviceName="kafka"
    username="<<MY_MESSAGEHUB_USERNAME>>"
    password="<<MY_MESSAGEHUB_PASSWORD>>";
};
EOF
```

This will have created a file `jaas.conf` in the `/home/wce/clsadmin` directory on the cluster.

Create a utility script to start the spark shell (for now we just have one executor):

```sh
$ cat << EOF > start_spark.sh
spark-shell --master local[1] \
       --files jaas.conf \
       --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0 \
       --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf" \
       --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf" \
       --num-executors 1 --executor-cores 1 
EOF
$ chmod +x start_spark.sh
```

Start the spark session using the utility script:

```sh
$ ./start_spark.sh
```

Now inside the spark shell, read the Kafka (Message Hub) stream.  Ensure you change the `kafka.bootstrap.servers` to match your service credentials:

```scala
val df = spark.readStream.
                format("kafka").
                option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka03-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net:9093,kafka04-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net:9093,kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net:9093,kafka02-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net:9093,kafka05-prod01.messagehub.services.eu-de.bluemix.net:9093").
                option("subscribe", "transactions_load").
                option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL").
                option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN").
                option("kafka.ssl.protocol", "TLSv1.2").
                option("kafka.ssl.enabled.protocols", "TLSv1.2").
                load()
```

We can test that our connection has worked ok:

```scala
df.writeStream.format("console").start()
```

After a while you should see some data printed to the console, e.g.

```
-------------------------------------------                                     
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|                 key|               value|            topic|partition|offset|           timestamp|timestampType|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|[35 34 30 33 36 3...|[7B 22 49 6E 76 6...|transactions_load|        7| 84874|2018-08-22 15:42:...|            0|
|[35 34 30 33 36 3...|[7B 22 49 6E 76 6...|transactions_load|        7| 84875|2018-08-22 15:42:...|            0|
|[35 34 30 38 33 3...|[7B 22 49 6E 76 6...|transactions_load|        7| 84876|2018-08-22 15:42:...|            0|
...
```

Setup the spark session so that it can access the COS instance:

```scala
val accessKey = "MY_COS_ACCESS_KEY"
val secretKey = "MY_COS_SECRET_KEY"
val bucketName = "streamingdata"

// arbitrary name for refering to the cos settings from this code
val serviceName = "myservicename"

sc.hadoopConfiguration.set(s"fs.cos.${serviceName}.access.key", accessKey)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set(s"fs.cos.${serviceName}.secret.key", secretKey)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set(s"fs.cos.${serviceName}.endpoint", "s3.eu-geo.objectstorage.service.networklayer.com")
```

We can test COS is setup by writing a dummy file:

```scala
import spark.implicits._

val data = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3,4,5))
data.toDF.write.format("csv").save(s"cos://${bucketName}.${serviceName}/data.txt")

spark.read.csv(s"cos://${bucketName}.${serviceName}/data.txt").collect()
```

The above test should output something like the following if reading and writing to COS was successful:

```
res7: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
```

Now try to write the streaming dataframe to COS:

```
df.
  writeStream.
  format("parquet").
  option("checkpointLocation", s"cos://${bucketName}.${serviceName}/checkpoint").
  option("path",               s"cos://${bucketName}.${serviceName}/data").
  start()
```

For me, this fails with:

```
scala> 18/08/22 15:43:06 WARN COSAPIClient: file status checkpoint/offsets returned 404
18/08/22 15:43:06 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 78c8c4af-f21d-457d-b5a7-56559e180634, runId = 50e8759e-0293-4fab-9b73-dd4811423b37] terminated with error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Not found cos://streamingdata.myservicename/checkpoint/offsets
    at com.ibm.stocator.fs.cos.COSAPIClient.getFileStatus(COSAPIClient.java:628)
    at com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem.getFileStatus(ObjectStoreFileSystem.java:486)
    at com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem.listStatus(ObjectStoreFileSystem.java:360)
    at com.ibm.stocator.fs.ObjectStoreFileSystem.listStatus(ObjectStoreFileSystem.java:336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog$FileSystemManager.list(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:412)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.getLatest(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$populateStartOffsets(MicroBatchExecution.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
```

Is this an issue with stocator, or Spark Structured Streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to the S3AFileSystem appears to have resolved the issue:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", accessKey)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secretKey)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.eu-geo.objectstorage.service.networklayer.com")

val s3Url = s"s3a://${bucketName}/"

...

df.
  writeStream.
  format("parquet").
  option("checkpointLocation", s"${s3Url}/checkpoint").
  option("path",               s"${s3Url}/data").
  start()
```

It looks as though this issue is with the stocator driver.

---

**UPDATE 23 Aug 2018:** This issue was fixed in Stocator [v1.0.24](https://github.com/CODAIT/stocator/releases/tag/v1.0.24), but stocator on IBM Analytics Engine hasn't yet been updated to this version.